# how to access form controls from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

How can I use every control in my form from another Class?
So as an example I can use txtName.text in class to edit it and do that for every control in my form

Comment: What is the goal here? Why can't the Form itself be used directly? Can you post a more detailed description of your setup? Unless you want to use a Controller-type class. There are already MV** frameworks built for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct mean.You want to control your form control object from another class 
1.You can pass the form object to another class via constructor(Form this)
2.Use MVP pattern .Buy  creating control as properties in mainform and create interface and for that form and pass the same interface to another class where you need to control the same

Answer (score 1):

The controls should only be accessable from the UI class. It would be bad practise to do not.

You can create properties to change the text or something else. Best option would be the MVVM pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good design but it can be done.

Change the access modifiers on your Controls to `Public`. You will then be able to reference them from any object which has access to your Form instance.

This can be done by selecting the Control in design mode, and changing `Modifiers` to `Public` in the properties panel.